# Browser back & forward and form autocomplete mess

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

On our webapp the page contains a filter form with some field, a SEARCH button, which calls a jQuery AJAX, loads the items according to the filter form data. From javascript we pushes the form filter values to the url to maintain the browser history.

When we press the BACK button, the page "reloads", but we see that the form values do not refresh to the current values. Examining the page source, we see that the html contains the textbox element with the proper value attribute (from the url values), but the textbox still displays the last value of the form. Sometimes. Sometimes it works.

We added the autocomplete="off" to the form values, which helps a little, "sometimes" went to "usually", the displayed values usually matches the html sources. But not always. We think that the browser cache is the bad guy - when we press the back or forward button sometimes the page does not refresh, but comes from "somewhere".

We added a web config cache setting:

```
<caching>
 <outputCacheSettings>
   <outputCacheProfiles>
     <add name="CacheProfileNone" noStore="true" varyByParam="*" duration="0" />
   </outputCacheProfiles>
 </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

and added the attribute to the controller action

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "CacheProfileNone")]
public ActionResult Index(QueryViewModel model)
{...}
```

but it didn't help. :( Sometimes when we press the back button wrong form values are displayed, not matching with the html values. The form values are not manipulated with custom javascript functions. We added onchange event with console.log output, and sees no log messages, so we think the form element display value does not depend on our decisions or code, but (we think) it depends on the browser things.

We are open new suggestions what to do next, to get the browser to always load the page and displays the current value as it is defined in the html source.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing (because you provided no code), but this doesn't work the way you think:

> From javascript we pushes the form filter values to the url to
>   maintain the browser history.

You need to investigate the History API `replaceState()` method.

Reference here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Yes, as I see when we pushes url-s to the history, the browser stores them in the history list, but clicking on BACK, the url changes, but won't reload the page.

Comment: Our web developer made a big revelation, that the pushState adds a new url to the browser history, but it does not exactly what she wanted to do - as the browser won't reload this url when navigating back in the history. Now she tries to solve the problem without pushShate or replaceState ... new method... But your answer was very important to her to understand what is the root problem. Thanks!